# Apache status - [1/1] The timeout specified has expired

Tags: apache-2.4, whm

When I check Apache status in WHM, it is full of "  [1/1] The timeout specified has expired" lines.

Does this mean there is something wrong with the server?

My website is configured with Cloudflare, and if I open too many URLs at once, I will get this error:

"Web server is returning an unknown error Error code 520"

Server details:
OS CentOS v7.9.2009 STANDARD standard
cPanel Version 110.0.10
Apache 2.4, PHP 8.2, and Ruby 2.4

Installed modules:
mod_mpm_worker
mod-qos
mod_bwlimited
mod_cache
mod_cgid
mod_deflate
mod_env
mod_evasive
mod_expires
mod_headers
mod_http2
mod_proxy
mod_proxy_fcgi
mod_proxy_http
mod_proxy_wstunnel
mod_ssl
mod_suexec
mod_suphp
mod_version
nodejs16